# Easy way to update certain field in database that is upper case?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to update the field 'prefix' in my course table to just have the FIRST letter capitalized and not the whole prefix.

Is there any easy way to do this is SQL?? Sample Output could look like 'Aadm' in the database for 'prefix'.

My table looks like:
[image]

Sample rows look like:
[image]

I have SQL that looks like:

```
WHERE CONCAT(prefix,code) LIKE '%".  $keywords . "%'");
```

Is it possible to user LOWER on prefix here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select prefix,
concat(upper(substring(prefix,1,1)),substring(lower(prefix) from 2)) as initcap
from course
```

try it in select form before update your field

if you're looking for prefixes where all chars are upper case use a regexp

```
where binary(prefix) regexp '^[A-Z]+$'
```

**EDIT**. Update query

```
update course 
set prefix =
concat(upper(substring(prefix,1,1)),substring(lower(prefix) from 2))
```

Comment: I get this error: SQL query: 

SELECT prefixCONCAT( UPPER( SUBSTRING( prefix, 1, 1 ) ) , SUBSTRING( LOWER( prefix ) 
FROM Course ) ) AS initcap
FROM Course
LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'concat(upper(substring(prefix,1,1)),substring(lower(prefix) from Course)) as ini' at line 2

Comment: Table: Course and Field Name is: Prefix.

Comment: Moreover I don't see "from 2". Don't mess with copy and paste :(

Comment: In your case is just an alias. In other rdbms is the name of the function that does this job for you. :)

Comment: I switched back, now its good I just switch 'Select' for 'Update' right?

Comment: I made backup and tried: UPDATE prefix, CONCAT( UPPER( SUBSTRING( prefix, 1, 1 ) ) , SUBSTRING( LOWER( prefix ) FROM 2) ) AS prefix FROM Course LIMIT 0 , 30    <-- gives error of #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT( UPPER( SUBSTRING( prefix, 1, 1 ) ) , SUBSTRING( LOWER( prefix ) FROM 2) ' at line 1

Comment: You need to read some basic tutorial of sql syntax. I've updated my answer with update query. Moreover you can't use update with an offset in limit clause in that way.

Comment: Beware that my query will update all the records, not only 30.